# Proof of the division algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic

I wasn't happy with the proof provided by the book, so I had an attempt at it, but I don't know if it's right. The theorem is:

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq0$. Then there exist unique $m,r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=mb+r$ and $0\leq r< |b|$.

I'm not going to attempt uniqueness here, and also just refer to the case for $a\geq 0, b>0$.

Suppose b|a. Then by definition, $\exists m$ such that $a=mb$. Then choose $r=0$ and the result is proved.

Suppose $b\nmid a$. Then $\exists m$ such that $\textrm{gcd}(a,mb)=1$ and $a-b <mb<a$. Then choose $r=a-mb$. Since $r=||a|-|mb||<|a-(a-b)|=b$ by the triangle inequality, then $0<r<b$, and the result is proved.

Comment: why such an $m$ exists, for example for $a=6,b=4$?

Comment: Could I say, instead, choose $m$ such that $m=\mathrm{max}\{x:x\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\;\;\; \mathrm{and}\;\;\; mx< a\}$?

Comment: I think you should use the classic proof.

Answer (score 1):

This classical result is proved in many algebra and number theory books.
There are two proofs for the division theorem, online available at [Poroofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Division_Theorem). Both use that [Integers bounded above have a greatest element](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integers_Bounded_Above_has_Greatest_Element).

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithmically**:

Set $m, r:= 0,a$. Then, as long as $r\ge b$, perform $m, r:=m+1,r-b$.

At any time, $a=mb+r$ holds, and when the iterations stop, $\color{green}{a=mb+r\land0\le r<b}$.

The iterations are guaranteed to stop, as $m\ge a$ yields $r=a-mb=a-ab\le0<b$.

---

Uniqueness is not very difficult.

Let $a=m'b+r'$ with $0\le r'<b$ and $a=m''b+r''$ with $0\le r''<b$.

Then by subtraction $(m'-m'')b+(r'-r'')=0$ so that $r'-r''$ is a multiple of $b$. This multiple cannot be other than $0$, as $|r'-r''|<b$. And $r'=r''$ implies $m'=m''$.

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose $b\nmid a$. Then $\exists m$ such that $\textrm{gcd}(a,mb)=1$** is a wrong assumption.

Take $a=4$ and $b=6$. $4$ does not divide $6$. However you can't find $m$ such that $\textrm{gcd}(4,m6)=1$.